# Square Otto event bus - how to test post and subscription with junit and roboelectric

Tags: android, junit, otto

How do i test an event bus in android . I am using Otto.  I have tried:

```
@Mock 
Bus bus;
```

delcared in my test. But now what i want to do is post an event and then check if the action was performed.   The event is created like this:

`new CoolEvent(true,true);`   but i dont know the command to check if the subscriber code executed. Can i use Captor ? How is this done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already found out how to test it. There are two things you can do. One is use Mockito and do this:

```
 ArgumentCaptor<OTTOEventClass> captor = ArgumentCaptor
                   .forClass(OTTOEventClass.class);
```

then since you hopefully have a bus in your test you can verify that a post to the bus was made with the OTTOEventClass object. 
like this:

```
verify(bus).post(captor.capture());
```

you could also verify certain flags in your OTTOEventClass are set like this:

```
assertThat(captor.getValue().isFlagSet(), equalTo(true));
```

The other thing you can do is just verify that a bus post was called with some type like this:

```
verify(bus).post(isA(OTTOEventClass.class));
```

the above just verifies `bus.post(new OTTOEventClass())` was called somewhere during your test and that the event that was posted is of type OTTOEventClass.

I dont test the otto subscriber because my tests are about testing my functionality not Otto. Let Otto be tested by square, i dont test framework i test my code & calls and my business logic.